# Selenium TestNG the same test for different dimensions

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testing, testng

can I run the same test using Selenium/TestNG/Java for browser windows with different dimensions? I think I have a solution, but I don't want to write the same  Code twice like this:

```
@Test(priority = 0)
public void pc {
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 "TheSameTestcode"
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void smartphone {
 Dimension d = new Dimension(420,600);
 driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
 "TheSameTestcode"
}
```

I saw something that would suit me in C # / Nunit and it looked something like this(for width 1000px,800px):

```
[TestFixture(1000)] 
[TestFixture(800)]     
[Test]
public void allDevices {
 "TheSameTestcode"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ReusableMethods{

public void setWindowSize(WebDriver driver,int x, int y){
  Dimension d = new Dimension(x,y);
  driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
}
public void sameCodeMethod(){
  "samecode here"
}
public boolean windowSizeAssertion(WebDriver driver, int x,int y){
  int height = dirver.manage().window().getHight();
  int width = dirver.manage().window().getWidth();
  if((height==x)&&(width==y)){
     return true;
  }
  else{
     return false;
  }

}
}

class TestNGTest extends ReusableMethods{
@Test(priority = 0)
public void pc {
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  samecodeMethod();
}

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void smartphone {
      setWindowSize(driver,100,200);
      samecodeMethod();
      Asset.assertTrue(windowSizeAssertion(driver,100,200));
    }

    }
```